# conditional operator in c++

Tags: c++

I am confused by the following codes and try to understand what they mean.

```
 if( (root->left == NULL) || (root->right == NULL) )
 {
    Node *temp = root->left ? root->left : root->right;
 }
```

it means `if root->left ==NULL` then `temp = root->left`? `else temp = root->right`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not exactly right, but u get the idea. This is a *conditional operator which takes three operands*.

```
 var = condition ? expression1 : expression2
```

is equivalent to

```
if( condition )
  var = expression1
else
  var = expression2
```

In your case it means

> if root->left != NULL then temp = root->left, else temp = root->right

instead of

> if root->left ==NULL then temp = root->left, else temp = root->right

Comment: The part of the question beginning with "it means..." is wrong (the condition should read `!= NULL`), so saying "you are right" is not correct.

Comment: Also, the operator's real name is the *conditional operator*, as in OP's question (see **5.16 Conditional operator [expr.cond]**.)

Comment: @DCoder, thanks for correcting me. I overlooked it the `==`operator.

Comment: The ternary operator `?:` returns a value whereas the `if` statement does not.

Answer (score 1):

It means the following: If `left` and `right` are `NULL`, then `temp` equals `NULL`, otherwise if `left` is `NULL`, then `temp` equals `right`, otherwise if `right` is `NULL`, then `temp` equals `left`.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. It means if `root->left == NULL` then `*temp = root->right`,
else if `root->right == NULL` then `*temp = root->left`,
else `*temp` will not be set.

There're 4 possible cases:

1. `root->left == NULL` and `root->right != NULL`, `*temp` will be `root->right`.
2. `root->left == NULL` and `root->right == NULL`, `*temp` will be `root->right`.
3. `root->left != NULL` and `root->right != NULL`, `*temp` will not be set.
4. `root->left != NULL` and `root->right == NULL`, `*temp` will be `root->left`.

Now you can see that 2nd and 3rd case may be potential problem.